# WinDbg Extension stepping

Tags: c++, debugging, windbg, dbgeng

I am trying to write an extension function that will run to the next call and then print out information about the next instruction.

I am using `IDebugControl::Execute` to run `tc`. As noted in the documentation, this call returns before the tracing has actually occurred. Sleeping or calling DispatchCallbacks does not see the `tc` trace occur before my extension returns.

**How can I allow the trace to happen without returning from the call?**

If I add my own DebugEventCallback then I can get notified of the triggered DebuggeeState and EngineState changes, but can't reach back into the engine from those callbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think It is not a good idea to make call changing a debugger state through IDebugControl::Execute ( g, t, etc )

At first you should implement step command:

```
control->SetExecutionStatus(DEBUG_STATUS_STEP_OVER);
control->WaitForEvent(DEBUG_WAIT_DEFAULT, INFINITE);
```

then you can make a matcher for call signature:

```
registers->GetInstructionOffset( &ip );
control->Disassemble( ip, ..., disasmStr, .. 
return  disasmStr
```

then can build your own tc:

```
while( CurrentInstruction() != 'call' ) makeOneStep()
```

you can use our python extension: [pykd.codeplex.com](http://pykd.codeplex.com)

Python code will look like:

```
from pykd import disasm, step
while disasm().instruction.find('call') < 0:
   step()
```